# Sharepoint 2010: best practice to migrate legacy data to sharepoint list

Tags: list, migration

I have to migrate some legacy data from stand-alone sql server database to sharepoint list.

I'm going to use programmatic approach and write a code that communicates with sharepoint list asmx web service.

Are there some "data transformation wizards" to simplify such a task or a better approach to port legacy data from sql server database to sharepoint list?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anything to do this specifically.  Writing the code for the inserts using the list web service is pretty quick and easy though.  You shouldn't be looking at more than a few dozen lines of code tops.

Comment: Thank you, Mike! I was advised also to put an eye on Office 2010 capabilities. It has Sharepoint export with some limitations

Comment: If you want to use MS Office, you can use Access to import data to SharePoint.  If you have linked tables from SQL that may make it pretty easy.  Here are some instructions.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-from-or-link-data-to-a-sharepoint-list-HA010341758.aspx